# Calculate the sine of a raster in the power of y / Python

Tags: python, rasterio, array

I have this code and my aim is to calculate the sine of my raster in the power of 0.8.

```
import os    
os.chdir('D:/NOA/Soil_Erosion/test_Project/Workspace/Input_Data_LS_Factor')
import rasterio    
import math 

data = rasterio.open('Slope_degrees_clipped.tif')    
band = data.read(1) # array of float32 with size (3297,2537)    
w = band.shape[0]    
print(w)

h = band.shape[1]    
print(h)

dtypes =data.dtypes[0]    
band_calc = math.sin(band)**0.8 # the formula I would like to calculate
```

However, the following error pops up: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars.

May you know how I should fix this?

P.S1. I tried to vectorize it (`np.vectorize()`) but it does not work as it needs a real number.

P.S2. When I use the `np.ndarray.flatten(band)` the same error occurs.

Comment: Use `np.sin()` instead of `math.sin()`?  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sin.html  Note that this expects angles in radians.

Comment: Thank you very much for this tip @mikewatt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For solving this issue you can use suggestion of @mikewatt (one line code solution). If you want to understand why this error pops up (only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars) when **sin** math method is used, you need to calculate the formula for each individual element in band array. Following script uses both methods (I used my own slope raster for corroborating my approach).

```
import os    
os.chdir('/home/zeito/pyqgis_data')
import rasterio    
import math 
import numpy as np

data = rasterio.open('slope_clip.tif')    
band = data.read(1) # array of float32 with size (3297,2537)    

band_calc = [ [] for i in range(len(band)) ]

for i,row in enumerate(band):
    for element in row:
        band_calc[i].append(math.sin(element*math.pi/180)**0.8)

band_calc2 = np.sin(band*np.pi/180)**0.8 # the formula I would like to calculate

print(band_calc)
print(band_calc2)
```

After running above script, it can be corroborated in following extract of both printed arrays that they are practically identical (except for the number of decimal places).

```
#with math method
[[0.4060400706043858, 0.4015786272365939, 0.3803876734044922, ..., 0.15096221490545716, 0.11142359584687449, 0.10171957992765607],
.
.
.
[0.16158203243605765, 0.27914982207926964, 0.4911149418076034, ..., 0.5004224927869971, 0.3748090783496892, 0.2963284367138169]]

#with numpy method

[[0.40604007 0.40157866 0.38038766 ... 0.1509622  0.1114236  0.10171958]
 [0.36817726 0.40977153 0.4641007  ... 0.12443032 0.10869407 0.11117965]
 [0.4355824  0.5659435  0.6422924  ... 0.12144282 0.10392076 0.11522116]
 ...
 [0.24135543 0.3750749  0.5000684  ... 0.5018844  0.37671152 0.22877638]
 [0.13608542 0.3038967  0.5011156  ... 0.49998093 0.39461306 0.3269125 ]
 [0.16158202 0.27914983 0.49111494 ... 0.5004225  0.37480912 0.29632843]]
```

Comment: @xunik thank you for your elaborate answer but for some reason it does not work for my case. In particular, the band_calc method results to an array where all the values are the same for every index while my slope raster has a variety of values and the band_calc2 method results in nan values for the majority of the pixels.

It also contains this warnings:
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sin

Comment: @xunik I have just seen that even if my tif file has proper values and the plot on Python looks nice, the rasterio package read the band (band = data.read(1)) as NoData values, and the calculations cannot be done. Once I fix the problem I will come back to you.

Comment: @xunik It finally worked out for me. I used the band_calc2 method without converting the degrees to radians. Thank you again for your elaborate answer.

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, before developed the script, I also tested the formula with radian angles in my desktop calculator and they matched. I would suggest you to search anomalous border pixels in your slope raster.  They can be produced when slope is calculated from DEM.